# Not able to keep the div fixed while scrolling in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an web application which displays products and its information as a modal when clicked. Now when I run this web application on my localhost, the modal appears and when I scroll it remains fixed at the center of the screen just as I want. This web application is a part of a bigger web application. I use iframe to integrate this web app in the bigger web app.
Now when I click on a product in this case I get the modal but when I scroll down the modal remains at the top, it doesnot come down when I scroll as it did before.
How to fix this?

I am attaching the code and some pics for your reference.

**HTML code for the modal**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div class="popup-wrapper product-detail ibox-content wrapper 
wrapper-content animated fadeInRight" data-spy="affix" data-offset-
top="400" ng-show="show" ng-click="closeModalOnOutside($event)">
<div class="popup row ibox-content modal-dialog" >
<button type="button" class="close"  ng-click="closeModal()">
<span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
<span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>

    <div class="images col-md-5 col-xs-12" >
    <div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" >
    <div class="text-center">
        <img ng-src={{item.Results.Results[0].image}}
             alt="">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12" >
        <div class="top-wrapper">
            <div class="name-wrapper">
            <h2 class="font-bold m-b-xs">
                                   {{item.Results.Results[0].name}}
                                </h2>

            </div>
            <div class="m-t-md">
                <h2 class="product-main-price">{{'$ 
    '+item.Results.Results[0].price}} </h2>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <h4>Details:</h4>
            <div class="small text-muted">
                        {{item.Results.Results[0] | tag }}

            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-
             click="goToItem( item.Results.Results[0].product_url)">
                <i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Purchase Item</button>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loader-wrapper" ng-hide="!isLoading">
        <div class="loader-inner">
            <div class="loader">
                <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-wave">
                        <div class="sk-rect1"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect2"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect3"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect4"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect5"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.popup-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(47, 64, 80, 0.3);
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
z-index: 50;
padding: 30px;
overflow: auto;
}


.popup-wrapper .popup {
position: relative;
min-height: 200px;
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.popup-wrapper .popup {
width: 700px;
display: flex;
margin: auto;
}

.product-detail .ibox-content {
padding: 30px 30px 50px 30px;
}
.ibox-content {
clear: both;
}

.ibox-content {
background-color: #ffffff;
color: inherit;
padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
border-color: #e7eaec;
border-image: none;
border-style: solid solid none;
border-width: 1px 0;
 }

.modal-dialog {
z-index: 2200;
}
```

**Image 1 when it works properly**
[When I scroll the modal also scrolls down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du7JD.jpg)

**Image2 when it doesnot work properly**
[When I integrate it using iframe the modal doesnot scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlb8p.jpg)

Comment: An iframe is an independent window instance with its own viewport. You know have fix positioned your element in regard to the iframe's viewport only. If the page that the iframe itself is on allows scrolling ... then you can't expect anything else to happen here.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to work around this problem

Answer (score 0):

1st suggestion I have for you is, could you not just remove it out of the iframe and place the markup of the modal with the rest of the doc?

If not then you could make another iframe which only has the modal box then position fixed that iframe.

```
iframe {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Envyme1/pen/YEgaMg)**